# Spring Data Neo4J Database Connection

Tags: configuration, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I am trying to connect to Neo4J database using Spring Data With following link (http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-neo4j/#quick-start). But it doesn't seem to work. Its not able to create Repository Implementation by itself. Thats why I am getting BeanCreationException. Here what I have tried so far.

1. PersistenceContext.java

> ```
> @Configuration
> @EnableTransactionManagement
> @ComponentScan("com.ksh.neo4j")
> @EnableNeo4jRepositories("com.ksh.neo4j.repositories")
> public class PersistenceContext  {
>
>   @Bean
>   public org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration getConfiguration() 
>   {
>       org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration = new org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration();
>       configuration.driverConfiguration()
>                    .setDriverClassName("org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver")
>                    .setURI("http://localhost:7474");
>       return configuration;
>   }
>   @Bean
>   public Neo4jTransactionManager transactionManager() {
>       return new Neo4jTransactionManager(getSessionFactory());
>   }
>   @Bean
>   public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
>       return new SessionFactory("com.ksh.neo4j.domains");
>   }
> }
> ```

2. PersonRepository.java

> ```
> @Repository
> public interface PersonRepository extends GraphRepository<Person> {
> }
> ```

3. PersonService.java

> ```
> @Service
> public class PersonService {  
>   @Autowired
>   private PersonRepository personRepository;
>
>   public Person save(Person person) {
>       return personRepository.save(person);
>   }
> }
> ```

4. PersonController.java

> ```
> @RestController
> @RequestMapping("/person/**")
> public class PersonController {
>   @Autowired
>   private PersonService personService;
>
>   @RequestMapping("/save")
>   public ResponseObject save(@RequestBody Person person) 
>   {
>       try {
>           personService.save(person);
>           return ResponseObjectCreator.createResponseObj(ResponseStatus.SUCSESS);
>       }
>       catch (Exception e) {
>           e.printStackTrace();
>       }
>       return ResponseObjectCreator.createResponseObj(ResponseStatus.FAILURE); 
>   }
> }
> ```

5. WebMvcConfig.java

> ```
>  @Configuration
>     @EnableWebMvc
>     @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.ksh.neo4j.controllers", "com.ksh.neo4j"})
>     public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {]
>       @Override
>       public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
>           configurer.enable();
>       }
>     }
> ```

6. POM.xml

> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
>   <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
>   <version>1.13.1.RELEASE</version>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
>   <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
>   <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>   <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
>   <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>   <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
>   <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
>   <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
>   <version>3.1.0</version>
>   <scope>compile</scope>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
>   <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver</artifactId>
>   <version>2.1.2</version>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
>   <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-core</artifactId>
>   <version>2.1.1</version>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
>   <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-http-driver</artifactId>
>   <version>2.1.1</version>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
>   <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
>   <version>3.1.3</version>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
>   <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
>   <version>3.1.3</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

**I am getting following exception**

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
>   Failed to instantiate [org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory]: Factory
>   method 'getSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.neo4j.ogm.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Could not load
>   driver: null.

Any Help Will Be Good.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say which version you are using, but if you are using 4.2.1 then the quick start seems to be missing transaction manager definition:

Add following to your PersistenceContext class:

```
@Bean
public Neo4jTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new Neo4jTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
}
```

Please refer to spring-data-neo4j documentation for further details.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#reference.getting_started.spring-configuration

Comment: I was using 4.2.1 but 4.2.1 version doesn't have class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration. So I changed version to 4.1.8. The solution given by you is giving me error which says "The constructor Neo4jTransactionManager(SessionFactory) is undefined". may be because of 4.1.8.

Comment: Yes, for 4.2.1 just remove the `extends Neo4jConfiguration`

Comment: @frant.harth I have updated question with exception and pom.xml. I am getting "Could not load driver: null." error.

Comment: @KSHiTiJ what does you driver configuration look like?

Comment: @frant.harth I update PersistenceContext.java. Please check.

Comment: @KSHiTiJ see the Java Configuration section in linked documentation for how to pass in the documentation to SessionFactory